# Skin Library for .NET with Mono support

Tags: c#, skin

Please suggest the skin control library .NET for WinForms (with good community, well written, well tested, fast). Another requirement is it should works for Mono.

--
Best Regards,
Murat

Answer (score 0):

You maybe not found you want because Mono use by default GTK# and .NET use Windows Forms. Mono have Windows Forms stack but this is not completed yet and maybe never will.